# Differential/Variation of a Functional in Gelfand/Fomin

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations

In the text of Gelfand and Fomin on Calculus of Variations, they define the variation of a functional $J$ (if it exists) to be the unique linear functional $\varphi$ satisfying:
$$J[y+h] - J[y] = \varphi[h]+\varepsilon\|h\|$$
where $\varepsilon \to 0$ as $\|h\| \to 0$.

Naturally I was curious if the differentiability of $J$ in this sense implied continuity of $J$, as in the case of the usual derivative. The answer seems to be yes if the linear functional $\varphi$ is assumed to be continuous, but I don't see any such assumptions in the text. Is this a standard assumption that is missing from the definition? Or am I wrong to desire such an assumption and we don't need the continuity of $\varphi$ to do meaningful work in this subject?

Comment: @Ilbant That thread discusses the relationship between the functional derivative and the usual derivative, but there is no mention of continuity of the linear functional.

Comment: One typically assumes continuity of $\varphi$ (Frechet derivatives are by definition bounded/continuous linear maps between Banach spaces).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for clarifying, I appreciate it.